# Histogram Subplot

Tags: python, dataframe, histogram

in the followng code I was trying to plot histograms of the 13 different things in subplots. I managed to do so, but it seems like the x and y values are interchanged.
Does anybody know how I need to change my code so that the every one of the 13 thirteen histograms look  as they should? This is a shortcut of how the table "mydata" looks.

```
     Alcohol  Malic_Acid   Ash  Ash_Alcanity  Magnesium  Total_Phenols  \
0      14.23        1.71  2.43          15.6        127           2.80   
1      13.20        1.78  2.14          11.2        100           2.65   
2      13.16        2.36  2.67          18.6        101           2.80   
3      14.37        1.95  2.50          16.8        113           3.85   
4      13.24        2.59  2.87          21.0        118           2.80   
..       ...         ...   ...           ...        ...            ...   
173    13.71        5.65  2.45          20.5         95           1.68   
174    13.40        3.91  2.48          23.0        102           1.80   
175    13.27        4.28  2.26          20.0        120           1.59   
176    13.17        2.59  2.37          20.0        120           1.65   
177    14.13        4.10  2.74          24.5         96           2.05
```

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.core.display import HTML as Center
%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [10, 10]
plt.rcParams['lines.markersize'] = 12
enter(""" <style>
.output_png {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style> """)
mydata = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\schal\OneDrive\UNI\Master\Maschinelles Lernen in der Verfahrentechnik\Übung\wine-clustering.csv")
features = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
names_features = features.columns.tolist()
f,a = plt.subplots(4,4)
print(a)
a = a.ravel()
print(a)
for idx,ax in enumerate(a):
    if idx <len(names_features):
        # Erstellen Sie hier nun die einzelnen Histogramme:
        mydatanew = mydata.iloc[:,idx]
        print(mydatanew)
        mydatanewnew = mydatanew.transpose(mydatanew)
        print(mydatanewnew)
        ax.hist(mydatanew, bins = 40)
        # Und beschriften Sie die einzelnen Diagramme (mit Titel und Achsenbeschriftung):
        ax.set_title(names_features[idx])
        ax.set_xlabel('x-Wert')
        ax.set_ylabel('y-Wert')
    else:
        ax.set_visible(False)
plt.tight_layout()
```

I tried to show all 13 histograms as subplots, but the x and y value seem to be interchanged